# I have no idea what's going on. :(

Tags: grub2

*Please note that my phone is the only way I can connect to the internet right now. since my PC is having an error which will be explained below.

**I might be able to borrow my friend's laptop if I need to download some files.

I installed Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS alongside Win7 with a cd. I have 2 TB on my C drive which I partitioned 500 GB for Ubuntu.

I was ask to restart to complete the installation which worked well. I was looking at the desktop when I noticed I don't have a network connection. So I tried to check but it doesn't detect any Wifi networks, even my neigbhor's. Then what I did was reboot the computer so I can look up for a solution online using Win 7. But all I see was "Device not found(or something similar)*insert a long line of numbers here*" then followed by:
"Entering rescue mode"
"grub rescue:"

So using my phone, (as it is the only way I can get to the internet aside from my PC) I found about the ls commands. But it's useless since every (hdX,Y) I have displays the unknown filesystem error.

I also can't boot any cd or usb because I think my BIOS is gone. These are all the details I can remember as I sit here on the toilet contemplating about the future of the universe.

Comment: Well the good news is that your BIOS is probably still there if you're getting to a grub prompt at all.  The BIOS needs to load before grub can load, so you probably just need to reconfigure it to boot CDs and USBs.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I just slept through the night lol.           So how do I reconfigure it to boot CDs and USBs with just the grub rescue prompt?

Comment: (part1) UPDATE: OMGOMGOMG now I'm very confused. I decided to open the case to check if my HD was actually hooked on. But ended up not doing so because I have no idea what I was looking at lol. So I just end up taking the cold cathodes which was not working anymore. I was about to take the HD out when I realized the wires are all at the other side of the case. Which will require me to take out the cage itself.

Comment: (Part 2) So I call it off for the day because I won't have enough time to do it today. So I put the cover back in, hooked everything up and turned it on to check if I had not misplaced something. To my SURPRISE, my computer works again! I am able to access BIOS or choose between Win7/ubuntu again. I gave it a few reboots to see if I'm not dreaming, but IT'S REAL!!!

Comment: Glad you got it all sorted out.  Isn't it nice when problems fix themselves? ;)